# got stuck in Cluster analysis, way forward?

Tags: r, clustering

I have a situation, where I need to classify items into groups (lets say 6). When I ran k-means 90% of my data fall in 1 group remaining 10% fall in other groups. What's next step?
In order to further group the data, I have taken the 90% data group and once again I ran k-means.This time I have 15 new groups within this new dataset. But now again 76% fell in one group remaining in 14 groups? How to deal in such situation?

Comment: What's the problem with such a situation?

Comment: @Scortchi I have a dataset of 77000 parts & its usage over 5yrs now  I need to classify them into 6 groups like mostly used/less used/recently used/not used. Since 90% of the data fell in one group I'm wondering how I can group them?

Comment: How many variables are you clustering on? Prima facie that classification doesn't sound like the sort of problem cluster analysis is all that useful for.

Comment: partID,monthly usage from jan08-dec13(72 varaibles).                   Can I run another cluster model on the large group to further divide?

Comment: If you want, but now it sounds even less like a case for cluster analysis.

Comment: Scortchi, there are few more variables apart from the mentioned monthly usage.

Comment: @suresh gorakala Your question does not seem to be focussed.Talking about clustering without variables/question items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of options with cluster analysis. You can choose different measures of distance and linkage. You could use hierarchical clusters instead of k-means. There are even fuzzy clusters. You have the `R` tag so I'm guessing you are using that.

On [this page](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Cluster.html) there is a large list of clustering functions in `R`. Each will have many options. Which have you tried?

Within the k means sort of idea, for instance, in `pam` you can alter the distance metric (use Manhattan instead of Euclidean) The 'flexclust` package offers lots of options.

Comment: Sure Peter will explore the pacakge.